# ggplot 2 - geom_bar - represent 2 factor variables as fill= and colour =

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to use a geom_bar and I want to use colors to represent two different variables (that are factors)
I want to use Color= Breakfast or Lunch and fill = Restaurant.
However, I end up with similar colors because they are just two levels of each factor.

[image]

Can anyone help me to set other colors of the inside and outside part of the bars and also to make the outline thicker?

```
ggplot(aes(x=Item, y= `Sugars (g)`, fill = Restaurant, color =Breakfast_lunch)) + geom_col()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your example code cannot be correct, it contains no term for the data, nor a `coord_flip` and has sugars, not fat as in the image. Speaking of which: please include the data, as plain text, in your question.

Comment: Use the ggplot `scale_color_...` and `scale_fill_...` functions

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have the fill colour of the bars (the `fill` aesthetic) tied to one variable, `Restaurant`, and the  outline/stroke colour (the `colour` or `color` aesthetic) tied to another one, `Breakfast_lunch`? In that case, you just want to change the actual colours used for each aesthetic (since they have the same defaults).

As @Jack Brookes suggests, you can use [`scale_fill_manual` and `scale_colour_manual`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-scales) to change these. You can supply them a named vector for the `values` argument: the names are the possible values of your variables, and the values are the colours you want them to appear as. For example:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Item, y = `Sugars (g)`, fill = Restaurant, color = Breakfast_lunch)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Burger King" = "red", "McDonalds" = "blue")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Breakfast" = "green", "Lunch" = "black"))
```

(those colours are hideous, though, so maybe choose better ones :P)

The colours you supply to `values` don't actually have to be named: if you don't provide the names (the values in your data), ggplot2 will just apply the colours in the order it encounters them in your dataset. So if you just care abouthaving different colours, you don't need to stress about that bit.

Also note, as @neilfws does, that your original `ggplot` call is missing a `data` argument (to your data frame) at the start. That's pretty important!

Comment: Hey, thank you.
I didn't include the data argument because I use %>% and the data was before that.
My main problem with this color and fill thing is that the outlines created by the color argument are really thin and hard to visualize.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense! If you want thicker outlines, I _believe_ you ought to be able to use the `size` argument with `geom_bar`.